# Regular expression to remove multiple parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, parentheses

I'm in need of a regular expression that can remove unnecessary/extra parenthesis in a string if found.

Example:

```
Bob Barker LIVE! (((Don't Miss out!)))
```

Wanted Result:

```
Bob Barker LIVE! (Don't Miss out!)
```

I don't care if users you them, as long as they don't over use them, and make sure to close them.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: To which replacement rules? Matching parentheses or just collapsing successive opening or close parens? -- Also, have you tried something yet?

Comment: What about `((fo(o)) ((bar)))` and `(((((foo)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy enough.

```
preg_replace('~[\(\)]+~', '', $string);
```

Edit: I didn't read your whole question. You still want parenthesis, just not duplicates.

```
preg_replace(array('~\(+~', '~\)+~'), array('(', ')'), $string);
```

Comment: it seems to remove all parentheses

Comment: This works great for me, however if the input is "Bob Barker LIVE! (((Don't Miss out!))(" The output is "Bob Barker LIVE! (Don't Miss out!)(" The last "(" isn't closed and should be removed.

Comment: @socca1157 you should list the requirements in the OP

Comment: @Esailija, I did though I suppose I wasn't very clear. "and make sure to close them."

Answer (score 3):

You can do this effectively with regex + recursion.  Do this until it stops doing anything:

`s/\(\([^()]*)\)\)/\(\1\)/g`

Now some comments:

1)  I'm leaving it to you to convert sed/perl style into PHP style regex.

2)  It's hard to read because ( ) are special characters.  Basically I'm saying "replace every `((...))` with `(...)` as long as `...` doesn't contain any `(` or `)`.  And to be honest I didn't test the mess I wrote down, but with this idea you should be able to repair.

This always removes them in pairs.

Basically the moral here is:  you asked a question you can't do with a simple regex - removing in pairs requires more state than the language permits.  But this one is low-hanging fruit if you iterate over the simple regex and eat the doubles from inside-out.

Comment: perl reports an error with this regex.  It works after I change it to this `s/\(\(([^()]*)\)\)/\(\1\)/g`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace( '/\(+(.*?)\)+/', '($1)', 'Bob Barker LIVE! (((Don\'t Miss out!)))');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/urC93o)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work properly for nested parentheses, but that's *really* difficult to get right with regex (and depending on the engine even impossible):

```
preg_replace(array('/\(+/', '/\)+/'), array('(', ')'), $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
preg_replace("([\\(]{1,})", "(", preg_replace("([\\)]{1,})", ")", $your_string));
```