# How to remove unnecessary parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999835/regular-expression-to-remove-multiple-parenthesis) but JavaScript. A few examples to illustrate my goal:

- (((foo))) => (foo)
- ((foo)) => (foo)
- (foo) => (foo)
- (foo (bar)) => (foo (bar))
- ((foo b)ar) => ((foo b)ar)
- (((a)b(c))) => ((a)b(c))

I have made a regex which should match the ones I want to change `/\({2,}[\s\S]*\){2,}/g` but I can't seem to figure out how to remove them.

Is there something like `String.replace(/\({2,}[\s\S]*\){2,}/g, '(${rest})')`?

Comment: The 3 first examples are trivial but the last 2 can't be done with regexes alone.

Comment: When regexes are your hammer everything looks like a thumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of struggling with regexes I'd suggest you try the classic  tokenize-parse-generate workflow. The idea is to parse a string into a data structure (in this case, nested arrays), simplify that structure and generate a new string from it.

Example:

```js
function tokenize(str) {
    return str.match(/[()]|[^()]+/g);
}

function parse(toks, depth = 0) {
    let ast = [];

    while (toks.length) {
        let t = toks.shift();
        
        switch (t) {
            case '(':
                ast.push(parse(toks, depth + 1));
                break;
            case ')':
                if (!depth)
                    throw new SyntaxError('mismatched )');
                return ast;
            default:
                ast.push(t);
        }
    }

    if (depth) {
        throw new SyntaxError('premature EOF');
    }

    return ast;
}

function generate(el) {
    if (!Array.isArray(el))
        return el;

    while (el.length === 1 && Array.isArray(el[0]))
        el = el[0];

    return '(' + el.map(generate).join('') + ')';
}


//

let test = `
(((foo)))
((foo))
(foo)
(foo (bar))
((foo b)ar)
((((foo)) bar))
((((((foo))bar))baz))
((((((((foo))))))))
foo
`;

for (let s of test.trim().split('\n'))
    console.log(s, '=>', generate(parse(tokenize(s))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
'(((foo))) => (foo)'.replace(/(\({2,})([a-zA-Z]*)(\){2,})/g, '($2)')
```

Or in general form:

```
str.replace(/(\({2,})([a-zA-Z]*)(\){2,})/g, '($2)')
```

I changed your regex a bit to capture the text matched by the regex in as numbered groups, so it is possible to use backreferences in `string.replace()`.

So basically you have 3 groups and you can reference them:

- $1 is gonna be open parenthesis like ((, (((, etc.
- $2 is the content between ((( content )))
- $3 is gonna be close parenthesis like )), ))), etc.

Happy Hacking :)

Comment: fails for e.g. `((((a))b))`. The trick is, the closing group must have the same length as the opening. Not solvable with regexes alone.

Comment: @georg Can you provide an alternate solution? Another scenario not covered is `((a)+(b))`

Comment: @MiXT4PE: added

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

```js
function RemoveDuplicateParenthesis(str) {
  var l = -1;
  while (l != str.length) {
    l = str.length;
    str = str.replace(/\({2,}.*\){2,}/igm, function(s) {
      var start = s.match(/^\(+/igm)[0].length;
      var end = s.match(/\)+$/igm)[0].length;
      s = s.replace(new RegExp("^\\({" + Math.min(start, end) + "}", 'igm'), '(');
      s = s.replace(new RegExp("\\){" + Math.min(start, end) + "}$", 'igm'), ')');
      return s;
    });
  }
  return str;
}
//Test
var pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre"));
var inputs = ['(((foo)))',
  '((foo))',
  '(foo)',
  '(foo (bar))',
  '((foo b)ar)',
  '(((foo b)ar))',
  '((foo (b)ar))',
  '((fo(o ((b)))ar))'
];
pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(inputs.map(function(s) {
  return {
    original: s,
    fixed: RemoveDuplicateParenthesis(s)
  };
}), null, 4);
```

Comment: `((a)+(b))` turns into `(a)+(b)`. What is your expected output?

Comment: `((a)+(b))` is the expected output as both parenthesis serve a purpose. Similarly `(((a)+(b)))` should become `((a)+(b))`