# How to analyse a formula with indefinite nesting?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a formula that has only elements that match `\w{3,4}`. There are four operators: `+`, `+-`, `/` (always enclose in parenthesis), `v` and normal parenthesis: `(` and `)`.

The entire formula is always enclose by parenthesis. I only need need to be able to nest to a depth of 4 but best would be unlimited depth if this is a possibility.

Here are a few examples for a valid formula that should be matched (xxxx is `\w{3,4}`):

- (xxxx)
- (xxxx/xxxx/xxxx)
- (xxxx+xxxx)
- (xxxx+-xxxx)
- ((xxxx/xxxx)+xxxx)
- (((xxxx/xxxx)+-xxxx)v(xxxx))
- ((xxxx/xxxx)+-(xxxx/xxxx)+xxxx)
- ((xxxx/xxxx)+-(((xxxx/xxxx)+-xxxx)/xxxx)+xxxx)
- ((((xxxx/xxxx)+-((xxxx/xxxx/xxxx)+-xxxx)/xxxx)+xxxx)v((xxxx/(xxxx/xxxx))+xxxx))

As you can see basically every `xxxx` can be replaced by an entire formula and it should still be valid. I'm unsure if regex is the way to go here so I would be open to other suggestions as well.

Here is my regex that works to depth 2 but seems over-complicated to me:

```
^(?:\(?(?:\w{3,4}|\(\w{3,4}(?:\/\w{3,4})+\))(?:\+-?(?:\w{3,4}|\(\w{3,4}(?:\/\w{3,4})+\)))*\)?$|\({2}(?:\w{3,4}|\(\w{3,4}(?:\/\w{3,4})+\))(?:\+-?(?:\w{3,4}|\(\w{3,4}(?:\/\w{3,4})+\)))*\)v\((?:\w{3,4}|\(\w{3,4}(?:\/\w{3,4})+\))(?:\+-?(?:\w{3,4}|\(\w{3,4}(?:\/\w{3,4})+\)))*\){2})$
```

Testing ground: https://regex101.com/r/YGDENq/2

---

**EDIT**: I am also using a parser to remove unnecessary parenthesis:

```js
console.log(fixParenthesis('(((((xxxx/xxxx)+-(xxxx/xxxx)+xxxx))))'));

function fixParenthesis(string) {
    function parse(tokens, depth = 0) {
        let ast = [];

        while (tokens.length) {
            switch (tokens[0]) {
                case '(':
                    tokens.shift();
                    ast.push(parse(tokens, depth + 1));
                    break;
                case ')':
                    if (!depth)
                        throw new SyntaxError('mismatched )');
                    tokens.shift();
                    return ast;
                default:
                    ast.push(tokens.shift());
            }
        }

        if (depth) {
            throw new SyntaxError('mismatched (');
        }

        return ast;
    }

    function generate(el) {
        if (!Array.isArray(el))
            return el;

        while (el.length === 1 && Array.isArray(el[0]))
            el = el[0];

        return `(${el.map(generate).join('')})`;
    }

    return generate(parse(string.match(/\(|\)|[^()]+/g)));
}
```

Could it be used to analyse the formulas instead of Regex?

Comment: What about a parser?

Comment: @Jan would you suggest this over regex in this case?

Comment: Yup, nested structures usually call for a parser. See https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-javascript/

Comment: To do this I think you would need to use either recursive regex (not directly supported with javascript) or you would have to break this into parts and analyse the expressions individually (i.e. creating a simple parser).

Comment: The last two are invalid, right? The number of `(` and `)`s is not the same. Well, try https://jsfiddle.net/xbdgwmqo/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right that was my mistake. I created them from the top of my head. Fixed

Comment: @Khauri I am already using [this parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57413626/7910454) to fix the parenthesis - could one build upon that?

Comment: In what way are you fixing the parenthesis? Removing unnecessary parenthesis? Automatically inserting missing parenthesis? And what action are you trying to build upon it?

Comment: @Khauri I am removing removing unnecessary parenthesis (see link in previous comment for details) and the action I would like to build upon it would be the analysis of the separated expressions

Comment: I understand that, but what are you trying to build on top of removing the parenthesis? Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking when you said "could one build upon that"

Comment: @Khauri The action I would like to build upon it would be the analysis of the separated expressions like you suggested

Comment: Could you update your question with your implementation of the above algorithm? Essentially you would just iterate through the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and perform the necessary operations for each node.

Comment: @Khauri I edited the question accordingly

Comment: So, what about [my approach](https://jsfiddle.net/xbdgwmqo/) to remove all operators and operands and then remove all paired parentheses and check if the string is empty?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you could make sure that there are no duplicate operands like `++` or `+-/` it would be perfect

Comment: But there is no `-` operator in your grammar. We can't remove any `-`. With this approach, we should be careful not to remove something that is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match and remove the operands with operators from the string and then remove paired `()` substrings until there is no match, and then check if the string is empty or not. If it is empty, the string was valid, else, it was invalid.

```js
var s = "((abcd/abc)+-(ab1/abd3)+dfg3)";
// Preliminary checks:
if (/^[()\w+\/-]*$/.test(s)) { // Only allowed chars?
 if (!/\bvv\b|(?!\+-)[+\/-]{2,}|[+\/-]+v\b|\bv[+\/-]+/.test(s)) { // No repeating delimiters?
  var prev=s;
  var res = s.replace(/\+-?|[-\/v]|\b\w{3,4}\b/g, '');
  while(res != prev) {
    prev = res;
    res = res.replace(/\(\)/g, '');  
  }
  if (res.length > 0) {
     document.body.innerHTML= "Not valid";
  } else {
     document.body.innerHTML = "Valid";
  }
 }
}
```

The  `/\+-?|[-\/v]|\w{3,4}/g` regex matches

- `\+-?` - a `+-` or `+`
- `|` - or
- `[-\/v]` - `-`, `/` or `v`
- `|` - or
- `\w{3,4}` - three or four word chars.

Removing parentheses is done with `.replace(/\(\)/g, '')` in a `while` block where the new string is compared with the previous one: if they are the same, no more replacements have been made and we may proceed to check if the string is empty or not.

Comment: Great idea, but: `((abcd/+-abc)++-+-+(ab1//abd3)+/dfg3)` => Valid

Comment: @MiXT4PE I think we can still use this approach but a couple more checks are necessary. I thought the strings do not need prevalidation.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded my parser, which already breaks down the formula to check for unnecessary parenthesis, as @Khauri suggested to instead validate each expression individually if the validation flag is set.

Here is the relevant code:

```
if (validating) {
    return deepFlat(arr).every(expr => RegExp('^(?:(?:\\+-?|\\/|v)?(?:\\w{3,4})?(?:(?:\\+-?|\\/)\\w{3,4})*)(?:\\+-?|\\/|v)?$').test(expr));
}
```

Here is the entire parser:

```js
console.log(fixAndValidate('(((((xxxx/xxxx)+-(xxxx/xxxx)+xxxx))))'));
console.log(fixAndValidate('(((((xxxx/xxxx)+-(xxxx/xxxx)+xxxx))))', true));

function fixAndValidate(string, validating = false) {
  function parse(tokens, depth = 0) {

    let ast = [];

    while (tokens.length) {
      switch (tokens[0]) {
        case '(':
          tokens.shift();
          ast.push(parse(tokens, depth + 1));
          break;
        case ')':
          if (!depth)
            throw new SyntaxError('mismatched )');
          tokens.shift();
          return ast;
        default:
          ast.push(tokens.shift());
      }
    }

    if (depth) {
      throw new SyntaxError('mismatched (');
    }

    return ast;
  }

  function generate(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr))
      return arr;

    while (arr.length === 1 && Array.isArray(arr[0]))
      arr = arr[0];

    if (validating) {
      return deepFlat(arr).every(expression => RegExp('^(?:(?:\\+-?|\\/|v)?(?:\\w{3,4})?(?:(?:\\+-?|\\/)\\w{3,4})*)(?:\\+-?|\\/|v)?$').test(expression));
    } else {
      return `(${arr.map(generate).join('')})`;
    }
  }

  try {
    return generate(parse(string.match(/\(|\)|[^()]+/g)));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return false;
  }
}

function deepFlat(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? deepFlat(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}
```